Build error right after creating a Next.js 15.0.1 project
I run npm run dev after creating a Next.js 15.0.1 project, and I got the following error:

./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-metadata-route-loader.js?filePath=
Module parse failed: Bad character escape sequence (11:62)
const fileSizeInMB = buffer.byteLength / 1024 / 1024
if (fileSizeInMB > 8) {
throw new Error('File size for Open Graph image "\app\favicon.ico" exceeds 8MB. ' +
|     (Current: ${fileSizeInMB.toFixed(2)}MB) |  +

I created the project using this command npx create-next-app@latest, and I selected Typescript, Eslint, Tailwindcss, and App router. I picked the default answer for the rest of the questions. I am using node v20.10.0 on Windows 10.
I checked the size of the favicon, and it's 25kb.

Having the same issue.
Using turbopack by running npx next dev --turbo fixed it for me temporarily.

The --turbo flag is actually documented as --turbopack, but both options work.

I think the error might be because the favicon.ico is supposed to be in the public folder, not in the app folder
Try:

Moving favicon.ico to public

Updating code references. You can just use /'favicon.ico' if its in public

Clearing cache/delete dependencies


rm -rf .next _node_modules
I would run a npm cache clean --force for good measure too.

Reinstall dependencies -- we nuked them with the rm -rf so need to reinstall

npm install

restart with npm run dev


check the file system .if you are using the same project name in the same folder, it brings this error.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
